# I keep getting an index out of error for position in my code, What is wrong with my list?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def find_median(some_nums):
    some_nums = [13,7,-3,82,4]
    number = len(some_nums)
    some_nums.sort()
    if number % 2 == 0:
            m1 = some_nums[number // 2]
            m2 = some_nums[number // 2 - 1]
            median = (m1 + m2) / 2
    else:
        median = some_nums[number // 2]
        return find_median()
some_nums = [13, 7, -3, 82,4]
print(find_median(some_nums))
```

I am supposed to find the median of the list using a function named find_median.

Comment: Your code does not compile. On line 11: you missed providing the argument to `find_median()`, therefore, I'm getting missing 1 positional argument error while running your code.

Comment: in the else part you are returning the function 'find_median' it should return 'median'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the calculated `median` instead of calling the function again

```
In [4]: def find_median(some_nums):
   ...:     number = len(some_nums)
   ...:     some_nums.sort()
   ...:     if number % 2 == 0:
   ...:             m1 = some_nums[number // 2]
   ...:             m2 = some_nums[number // 2 - 1]
   ...:             median = (m1 + m2) / 2
   ...:     else:
   ...:         median = some_nums[number // 2]
   ...:     return median
   ...:
   ...: some_nums = [13, 7, -3, 82,4]
   ...: print(find_median(some_nums))
7
```